# Converting uploaded image to grey scale and downloading it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, intervention

I have made an app where user adds two images from back end one is black & white and the other colored which definitely takes more space on the server now I am writing a function which can convert colored image to gray scale this way the load on the server will reduce now I am stuck in a situation when I use intervention library it always give error that file is empty can anyone help me resolve what I am doing wrong here is my code that I am currently using.

```
public function download(Request $request) {
    $input = Input::all();
    $sheet = Sheet::find($request->id);
    if ($input['color-type'] == 'color') {
        $file = public_path() . "/large/s/" . $sheet->sheet_f_id . '-s.jpg';
        return Response::download($file);
    } else {
        $file = public_path() . "/large/s/" . $sheet->sheet_f_id . '-s.jpg';
        $image = Image::make($file);
        $grayScale = $image->greyscale();
        return Response::download($grayScale);
    }
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
$image = Image::make(public_path($file));
```

Comment: and about reducing the load of the server i don't think making greyscale images will help you with that , the user won't be happy to see the images changed there color , you  need to reduce the quality of the image and save it as jpg

Comment: Making image this way gives me the following error now `Image source not readable`

Comment: could you dump the $file variable ? and give the result

Comment: Here is the result `"D:\xampp\htdocs\wikistaging\public/large/s/00-00-05-003-s.jpg"`

Comment: i guess that's why , you shouldn't save the images like that , you should save them relative to the root folder using public_path($file);

so the first function that save the original image should have relative link to the image not the full path;

Comment: Sir with all due respect I am not saving the image the code that actually storing the image is not written by me and I am not allowed to change that code as well can you suggest me some way to download these images after applying gray scale filter